# How do I prevent Zend from trying to bind my MySQL values?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have a query like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table SET `data` = '{\"m\":50}'
```

Granted the JSON data is much larger in my real query, I always get the error:

`Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: Invalid bind-variable name ':50'`

This is when I do `$connection->query( $sql );`

In the past I've solved this by using single quotes rather than double quotes around my values, but for some reason it's not working now. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

On top of the accepted answer, here is the code I used to make sure I can still pass `new Zend_Db_Expr("NOW()")` to my function, but have something like the JSON data prepared properly.

```
foreach ( $params as $key => $value ) {

  // Can't use ? for anything that requires an expression, such as NOW()
  if ( $value instanceof Zend_Db_Expr ) {
    $db_keys[] = $connection->quoteInto( "`{$key}` = ?", $value );
  }
  else {
    $db_values[] = $value;
    $db_keys[]   = "`{$key}` = ?";
  }

} // foreach params

$sql    = "INSERT IGNORE INTO {$table} SET " . implode( ', ', $db_keys );
$result = $connection->query( $sql, $db_values );
```

Comment: `... SET 'data' = '{\"m\": 50}'` ? (space between `:` and `50`) [might qualify as workaround only, I can imagine but perhaps solves for the moment]

Comment: @hakre the JSON is coming out of PHP `json_encode( $array )` - I'm not choosing the spacing

Comment: I already placed a "disclaimer" :), but now as you commented that, actually you perhaps can with a little flag: https://eval.in/45265 [I know this is still some kind of workaround I would not be confident with either]

Comment: @hakre Not a bad idea, but I don't want to store all the literal space for all the spaces to make Zend happy

Comment: As written, I wouldn't want either. Have you taken a look into ZEND for docs how to escape the special letter `:`? I normally would go that way (my workaround suggestions are just my lazy pulse)

Comment: If you're getting that error, then you've build your query string improperly. the `{"m":50}` portion should be passed in as a bound parameter, not embedded in the query string. If you embed `:whatever` in the query string and pass it to prepare, it is not Zend's fault that the `:50` is seen as an invalid placeholder.

Comment: Easy and put. I'd say that nails it.

Comment: @MarcB As far as I know there is no `insert ignore` option in Zend other than writing out the query myself...

Comment: but there are prepared statements: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html

Comment: @MarcB write that as answer so I can give it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't embed data like that in a query string. As you're finding out, it's subject to mis-interpretation as an invalid placeholder. Use a prepared statement with placeholders instead:

```
$stmt = $db->query("INSERT IGNORE ... `data` = ?", array('{"m":50}'));
                                               ^----placeholder
```

Comment: One more question: How can I make one of the keys properly evaluate `new Zend_Db_Expr( "NOW()" )` when using a prepared statement?

Comment: I did a `$value instanceof Zend_Db_Expr` to do either `$connection->quoteInto( "`{$key}` = ?", $value );` OR pass the value as the second argument to query for the prepared statement

Comment: The whole point of placeholders is to keep the DBMS from treating the data as an executable bit. If you need to use an sql function, you'd have to either embed it into the query directly, e.g. `data=NOW()` instead of `data=?`, or do the equivalent function in PHP and send in the results as plain data.

Comment: Yeah I did something like that, added to my question up top for future reference